# How to associate screen reader-accessible text with a video.js element, such as the Play button

Tags: javascript, accessibility, video.js

The context of the issue is passing `Section 508` accessibility testing of html pages containing multiple embedded videos, 4 in this case. The failure was described as:

> "Play button has no screen-reader identification of video title about to be played."

The specific implementation of the `video.js` player is a `Brightcove` player. The goal is for a screen reader to read the title of the video upon tabbing to the play button, before the button is activated.

Adding an `aria-label=` line to a video code-enclosing `div` in the embedding code allows screen reader access. But user must still tab again to actual player controls, because tabbing hasn't yet entered the `video.js` code's default tab-ordering of control elements. Also, it seems doing it that way interferes with logical tab ordering. The order goes through all the `div` containers first, then back to the `Play button` of the 1st video. I wasn't able to correct that with `"tabindex=" numbers` – they seem to be ignored.

Comment: Could you provide a JS fiddle to look at as you mention a specific player 'brightcove'. Odds are that the play button itself just needs some 'visually hidden' text adding to it (assuming it is actually a button and not a styled `div`) to explain what the video is. Without seeing some code though I am guessing.

Comment: I'm new to JS fiddle and hope I've done this in a useable way: 
https://jsfiddle.net/OpsTao/4m6oyd8z/ _ 

For simplicity and because this is a one-time thing, the needed CSS and JS is in the HTML page. _ 

Brightcove's "Advanced" code rather than "Standard" video.js code is being used, because the page also must have .js that prevents multiple videos from being played simultaneously. (That was a previous accessibility test failure.) _ 

Here is a link to Brightcove Player API info: 
https://support.brightcove.com/brightcove-player

Comment: The page has several of the original problems solved. the jsfiddle is updated to reflect that: https://jsfiddle.net/OpsTao/4m6oyd8z/2/#&togetherjs=GsGEpPrMvv 
I am still looking for a way to associate hidden text for the video title, such as aria-label text, with the Play button. The current solution of using aria-label text (on the div containing the video player) is not fully compliant with 508 testing standards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of tabbing order when using "advanced" embedding code was solved by a deceptively simple solution:

```
  tabindex="0"
```

added to the **div** containers enclosing each set of video.js code did the job. To further clarify: This refers to Brightcove's "advanced" code, which is of the form beginning like

```
<video-js data-account= ...
```

whereas their "standard" code uses an iframe.

Comment: The tab order issue has been solved, but not the issue of having the video player Play button associate screen-reader-accessible text to identify the specific video title, thus distinguishing it from other videos on the same page. See new comment to original question, with revised jsfiddle.